# HTML multi input file is sending one input only

Tags: php, html, forms, laravel, input

I have this input code in my form :

```
<input name="photos" type="file"  multiple>
```

In my controller class that handle the form inputs :-

```
$photos = Input::file('photos');
        $count = count($photos);
```

I am using the count() method just to make sure whether the form is sending a multiple files or not.
The return of count method is "1" while I've selected 6

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by changing the input name, from :-

```
<input name="photos" type="file"  multiple>
```

To:

```
<input name="photos[]" type="file"  multiple>
```